# Unable to get ContentControl in MahApps ToggleSwitch to be bold

Tags: wpf, mahapps.metro, wpf-style

I have taken and created a new Style for MahApps ToggleSwitch. After modifying it looks like below. I have it set to alternate between Yes and No instead of On and Off. I have also changed the size and coloring for ThumbIndicatorBrush.

[image]

I am trying to bold the 'No'

Here is the style I created below.

```
<Style x:Key="RuleItemToggleButtonControlTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type controls:ToggleSwitch}">
    <Setter Property="ContentPadding" Value="0,0,4,0"/>
    <Setter Property="controls:ControlsHelper.HeaderFontSize" Value="{DynamicResource ToggleSwitchHeaderFontSize}"/>
    <Setter Property="controls:ControlsHelper.HeaderMargin" Value="0,0,0,5"/>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{DynamicResource ToggleSwitchFontFamily}"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{DynamicResource ToggleSwitchFontSize}"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource TextBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="HeaderFontFamily" Value="{DynamicResource ToggleSwitchHeaderFontFamily}"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="OffSwitchBrush" Value="{DynamicResource GrayBrush4}"/>
    <Setter Property="OnSwitchBrush" Value="{DynamicResource AccentColorBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type controls:ToggleSwitch}">
                <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0.3" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="Header"/>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0.3" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="Content"/>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0.75" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="Switch"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Grid Background="Transparent">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition x:Name="firstCol" Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition x:Name="secCol" Width="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <ContentControl x:Name="Header" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding HeaderStringFormat}" FontWeight="{TemplateBinding controls:ControlsHelper.HeaderFontWeight}" FontSize="{TemplateBinding controls:ControlsHelper.HeaderFontSize}" FontFamily="{TemplateBinding HeaderFontFamily}" IsTabStop="False" Margin="{TemplateBinding controls:ControlsHelper.HeaderMargin}"/>
                        <ContentControl x:Name="Content" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentStringFormat}" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" IsTabStop="False" Margin="{TemplateBinding ContentPadding}" Grid.Row="1"
                                        Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                        <controls:ToggleSwitchButton x:Name="Switch" BorderThickness="1"  Height="22" Width="40" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Grid.Column="1" FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" OffSwitchBrush="{TemplateBinding OffSwitchBrush}" OnSwitchBrush="{TemplateBinding OnSwitchBrush}" Grid.Row="1" Style="{TemplateBinding ToggleSwitchButtonStyle}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" ThumbIndicatorWidth="{TemplateBinding ThumbIndicatorWidth}" ThumbIndicatorDisabledBrush="{TemplateBinding ThumbIndicatorDisabledBrush}" ThumbIndicatorBrush="{TemplateBinding ThumbIndicatorBrush}" VerticalAlignment="Center"></controls:ToggleSwitchButton>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsChecked" Value="True"/>
                            <Condition Property="Content" Value="{x:Null}"/>
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Content" TargetName="Content" Value="Yes"/>
                        <Setter Property="ThumbIndicatorBrush" Value="{StaticResource AccentColorBrush}"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="Switch" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource AccentColorBrush}"></Setter>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsChecked" Value="False"/>
                            <Condition Property="Content" Value="{x:Null}"/>
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Content" TargetName="Content" Value="No"/>
                        <Setter Property="ThumbIndicatorBrush" Value="{StaticResource ControlBorderBrush}"></Setter>
                        <Setter TargetName="Switch" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource ControlBorderBrush}"/>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Header, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="{x:Null}">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Header" Value="Collapsed"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <Trigger Property="ContentDirection" Value="RightToLeft">
                        <Setter Property="ContentPadding" Value="4,0,0,0"/>
                        <Setter Property="Grid.Column" TargetName="Content" Value="1"/>
                        <Setter Property="Grid.Column" TargetName="Switch" Value="0"/>
                        <Setter Property="Width" TargetName="firstCol" Value="Auto"/>
                        <Setter Property="Width" TargetName="secCol" Value="*"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="ThumbIndicatorBrush" Value="{DynamicResource BlackBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="ThumbIndicatorDisabledBrush" Value="{DynamicResource GrayBrush4}"/>
    <Setter Property="ThumbIndicatorWidth" Value="13"/>
    <Setter Property="ToggleSwitchButtonStyle" Value="{DynamicResource MahApps.Metro.Styles.ToggleSwitchButton}"/>
    <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate" Value="{DynamicResource ValidationErrorTemplate}"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
</Style>
```

I have tried setting the font-weight to bold for the 
ContentControl named 'Content' with no luck. I even tried taking the ContentControl out and using a TextBlock and adjusting the text property instead of content property and it still doesn't honor the font-weight. I also tried getting it to be bold on the default template and was unable to do. Anyone know how I can get that to be bold?

Comment: The ToggleSwitch from MahApps uses a default font for the header and the content. The content uses the ToggleSwitchFontFamily which is 'Segoe UI Semibold, Segoe UI, Lucida Sans Unicode, Verdana'. So the content will uses the `Segoe UI Semibold` which is already bold.

Comment: Ah! You can post as answer and I will mark as answer. Thanks for your time and answering love the library!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ToggleSwitch from MahApps uses a default font for the header and the content. The content uses the ToggleSwitchFontFamily which is 'Segoe UI Semibold, Segoe UI, Lucida Sans Unicode, Verdana'. So the content will uses the `Segoe UI Semibold` which is already bold.

Answer (score 0):

@punker76's answer is correct. The reason I asked the question is the yes/no did not match the metroheaders font and font weight. In his answer one of the things he brought up triggered my thought process for a work around. As it was a different font and semibold. I did not realize it was a different font which made me think it just wasn't bold but it was a different font and that is why it did not look the same as the MetroHeaders which is what I was really after. So what I did was use the TextElement.FontFamily and TextElement.FontWeight attached properties and attached them to the control to get look I was looking for.

```
TextElement.FontFamily="{TemplateBinding controls:ControlsHelper.HeaderFontFamily}"
TextElement.FontWeight="Bold"
```